# Trigger countdown with 433MHz transmission

Tags: arduino-leonardo, arduino-micro, time

I would like to use an arduino to read 433 MHz transmission from multiple Soil Moisture Sensors. Since I can never be sure all transmissions reach the receiver I'd like to set a countdown from the moment the first transmission is received. If another transmission is received, the countdown starts again.
After a defined amount of time (e.g. 10 Minutes) without any more signals or if all signals have been received (e.g 4 Sensors) the receiving unit should stop and come to decision based on the data it got to the point.

For transmitting and receiving I am using the `<RCSwitch.h>`library.

The loop of the receiving unit and one Sensor looks like this:

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
void Setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
mySwitch.enableReceive(4);
} 
void loop() {
if (mySwitch.available()) {
int value = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();

if (value == 0) {
  lcd.clear();
  Serial.print("Unknown encoding");
  } 
  else {
  Serial.print(mySwitch.getReceivedValue());
  Serial.print("%");
}
```

The full code includes some differentiation mechanism for all sensors but I figured that might not be relevant for my question.

Question:
What's the best way to do this without a real time clock module. As far as I know I can't wait by using `delay(...)`since then I won't receive any data while the processor waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say *The full code includes some differentiation mechanism for all sensors* so I'll assume there's some function `GetSensorId()` that returns 0 to NUM_SENSORS - 1.

So, you need to keep track of a) how many sensors have reported in and b) time since the last report. You can't just count how many sensors have reported in since there may be a chance one could report in more than once. So I would use an array:

```cpp
// Assume you never receive 0 from sensor.
const int NO_DATA = 0;
const int NUM_SENSORS = 4;
int sensor_data[NUM_SENSORS];

void setup() {
    // Initialize array
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
        sensor_data[i] = NO_DATA;
    }
}
```

Also, a variable to keep track of time of last message:

```cpp
uint32_t last_message_time = 0;
```

So, in `loop()`:

```cpp
void loop() {
    // Check for data
    if (mySwitch.available()) {
        int value = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();
        if (value == 0) {
            lcd.clear();
            Serial.print("Unknown encoding");
        } 
        else {
           // Determine which sensor sent the data
           int sensor_id = GetSensorId();
           Serial.print(value);
           Serial.print("%");
           // Save the data and the time of the message
           sensor_data[id] = value;
           last_message_time = millis();
       }
    }
    // See if all sensors reported
    byte sensors_reported = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
        if (NO_DATA != sensor_data[i]) {
            sensors_reported += 1;
        }
    }

    // When 0 sensors have reported in, do nothing
    if (0 != sensors_reported) {
        // Otherwise, at least one sensor
        // check the time
        uint32_t elapsed = millis() - last_message_time;

        // If have all data or time's up, do something
        if (NUM_SENSORS == sensors_reported || elapsed > SENSOR_TIMEOUT) {
            // Do something

            // Reset state
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
                sensor_data[i] = NO_DATA;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay .. it took me some time to try everything . It seems to work just the way i wanted. Thank you very much.